# Сложение чисел одного столбца текстового документа c#

Tags: c#

Есть 2 файла txt, в которых числа в 3 столбика через запятую. Первые 2 столбца одинаковые, третьи отличаются. Мне нужно было из значений третьего столбца первого файла вычесть значения третьего столбца второго файла и поделить на значения третьего столбца первого файла. Затем всё это поместить в новый документ. С этим я справился. Но появилась необходимость сложить все числа, которые получились в новом третьем столбце и вывести сумму (например в label, textbox, неважно). Вот тут загвоздка, не получается.. 
PS: DAT - это тот же txt. Всё, что посчиталось сначала выводится в RichTextBox, потом через кнопку "Сохранить как" я сохраняю новый DAT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Профили
{
    public partial class Frm : Form
    {
        public struct strDAT1
        {
            public double x1, y1, z1;
        }
        List<strDAT1> lDAT1 = new List<strDAT1>();
        public struct strDAT
        {
            public double x, y, z;
        }

        List<strDAT> lDAT = new List<strDAT>();

        public Frm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Frm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) Close();
        }

        private void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool fDAT1 = ((Button)sender).Name == "btDAT1";
            OD.Filter = fDAT1 ? "Файлы DAT|*.dat" : "Файлы DAT|*.dat";
            if (OD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TXT.Text = "";
                if (fDAT1)
                {
                   lbDAT1.Text = OD.FileName;
                    lDAT1.Clear();
                    using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(OD.FileName))
                    {
                        while (SR.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                            strDAT1 str;
                            string r = SR.ReadLine().Trim();
                            if (r != "")
                            {
                                string[] s = r.Split(' ');
                                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                                    s[i] = s[i].Replace('.', ',');
                                double.TryParse(s[0], out str.x1);
                                double.TryParse(s[1], out str.y1);
                                double.TryParse(s[2], out str.z1);
                                lDAT1.Add(str);
                            }
                        }
                        SR.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lbDAT.Text = OD.FileName;
                    lDAT.Clear();
                    using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(OD.FileName))
                    {
                        while (SR.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                            strDAT str;
                            string r = SR.ReadLine().Trim();
                            if (r != "")
                            {
                                string[] s = r.Split(' ');
                                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                                    s[i] = s[i].Replace('.', ',');
                                double.TryParse(s[0], out str.x);
                                double.TryParse(s[1], out str.y);
                                double.TryParse(s[2], out str.z);
                                lDAT.Add(str);
                            }
                        }
                        SR.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void btCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TXT.Text = "";

            string txt = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lDAT1.Count; i++)
            {

                double x1 = lDAT1[i].x1; 
                double y1 = lDAT1[i].y1;
                double z1 = lDAT1[i].z1;
                double x = lDAT[i].x;
                double y = lDAT[i].y;
                double z = lDAT[i].z;
                double xx, yy, zz;


                xx = (x - x1);
                yy = (y - y1);
                zz = (z - z1) / z;


                int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OD.FileName).Length;

                if (x == x1 && y == y1)
                {


                        txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + zz +  "\r\n";//+ count

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Отличаются значения первых двух столбцов DAT-файлов");

              }
            TXT.Text = txt.Replace(',', '.');
            btSave.Focus();

            }



        private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                //using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(SD.FileName))
                {
                    TXT.SaveFile(SD.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    //SW.WriteLine(TXT.Text);
                    //SW.Close();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю ещё. Мне нужно сложить все zz, и на форму куда-нибудь написать.

Comment: Вообще мыслей нет, как это сделать сразу же. Можно конечно сохранить сначала третий документ, потом снова его загрузить и т.д., но это же глупо..

Comment: вряд ли кто-то будет заниматься этим и копаться в куче кода. Минимизируй код и убери лишнее из вопроса. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вопрос решён...Ответ оставил ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ в 3 строчках.

1. double sum = 0; (Завели переменную)
2. sum+=zz; (Сложили нужные числа)
3. label1.Text = sum.ToString(); (Куда-нибудь вывели сумму)

   private void btCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

   ```
       TXT.Text = "";
       double sum = 0;
       string txt = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < lDAT1.Count; i++)
       {

           double x1 = lDAT1[i].x1; 
           double y1 = lDAT1[i].y1;
           double z1 = lDAT1[i].z1;
           double x = lDAT[i].x;
           double y = lDAT[i].y;
           double z = lDAT[i].z;
           double xx, yy, zz;

           xx = (x - x1);
           yy = (y - y1);
           zz = (z - z1) / z;
           sum+=zz;
           int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OD.FileName).Length;

           if (x == x1 && y == y1)
           {


                   txt += "" + x + " " + y + " " + zz +  "\r\n";//+ count

           }
           else
               MessageBox.Show("Отличаются значения первых двух столбцов DAT-файлов");

         }
       TXT.Text = txt.Replace(',', '.');
       label1.Text = sum.ToString();
       btSave.Focus();

       }
   ```